# Series convergence by Gauss Test

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I want to try to prove that the $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n!e^n}{n^{n+p}}$$  series convergent for $p>1.5$ with Gauss Test but failed? Gauss Test said if
$\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}$ can be represnted as
$\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}=\lambda+\frac{\mu}{n}+b_n$
where $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ absolutely convergent

then

1. $\lambda>1$ convergent
2. $\lambda<1$ divergent
3. $\lambda=1, \mu>1 $ convergent
4. $\lambda=1, \mu\leq1 $ divergent

**My work**: I found that
$$\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}=\frac{1}{e}{(1+\frac{1}{n})}^{n+p}=\frac{1}{e}(1+1/n)^{n+p}=\frac{1}{e}(1+\frac{n+p}{n}+\frac{(n+p)(n+p-1)}{2}\frac{1}{n^2}+\dots)),$$ and then stopped and didnt see a continuation.

Comment: It would be useful to show how you failed with applying the test.

Comment: I write in this way. $\frac{1}{e}(1+1/n)^{n+p}=\frac{1}{e}(1+\frac{n+p}{n}+\frac{(n+p)(n+p-1)}{2}\frac{1}{n^2}+...))$ and then stoped and didnt see continuation.

Comment: @Genieinthebottle I edited your question putting your work about the ratio $\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}$. Next time include your work in your question. It helps!

Comment: @RobertZ I wonder how were you able to describe "my work" even before OP described this in the comment? :)

Comment: @user See below through the comments. I am not a mind-reader...

Comment: @RobertZ Thanks. I see now.

Answer (score 6):

Note that, as $n$ goes to infinity,
$$\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}=\frac{n!e^n}{n^{n+p}}\cdot \frac{(n+1)^{n+1+p}}{(n+1)!e^{n+1}}=\frac{(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n+p}}{e}=1+\frac{p-\frac{1}{2}}{n}+O(1/n^2)$$
where
\begin{align}
\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+p}&=\exp\left((n+p)\ln(1+\frac{1}{n})\right)=\exp\left((n+p)(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2n^2}+O(1/n^3))\right)\\&=\exp\left(1+\frac{p-\frac{1}{2}}{n}+O(1/n^2)\right)
=e\left(1+\frac{p-\frac{1}{2}}{n}+O(1/n^2)\right).\end{align}
Hence, according to Gauss Test, the series is convergent when $p-\frac{1}{2}>1$, that is $p>\frac{3}{2}$.

Comment: I suggest we write $(1+\frac {1}{n})^{n+p}=$ $(1+\frac {1}{n})^{n+1/2}\cdot (1+\frac {1}{n})^{p-1/2}=$ $e(1+O(1/n^2))(1+\frac {1}{n})^{p-1/2}=$ $e(1+O(1/n^2))(1+\frac {p-1/2}{n}+O(1/n^2))=$ $e(1+\frac {p-1/2}{n}+O(1/n^2)), $ which is basically the same idea but  perhaps a  little simpler.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet How do you know that $x=\frac12$ in $\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n+x}$?

Comment: @user.  Typo? What is that???

Comment: @DanielWainfleet That is a question.

Comment: @user. What is $x$? There is no $x$  in my comment  nor in the Q nor the A....and I didn't mention $\ln.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet There are two $x$ in my comment. Can you recognize the pattern? Hint: in your comment you chose $x=\frac12$. And I did not mention $\ln$ as well.

Answer (score 4):

**Proof with Stirling formula :**

You have
$$\frac{n!e^n}{n^{n+p}} \sim \sqrt{2\pi n} \frac{n^ne^n}{e^nn^{n+p}} \sim \frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{n^{p-\frac{1}{2}}}$$

which is the general term of a convergent series, since $p>1,5$. So the given series converges.

**Proof with Gauss test :**

Let $$a_n = \frac{n!e^n}{n^{n+p}}$$

You have
$$\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}} = \frac{n!e^n(n+1)^{n+1+p}}{(n+1)!e^{n+1}n^{n+p}} = \frac{1}{e}\left(\frac{n+1}{n} \right)^{n+p} = \exp \left[(n+p)\ln \left( 1+\frac{1}{n}\right)-1 \right]$$

i.e.
$$\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}} =  \exp \left[(n+p)\left(\frac{1}{n} -\frac{1}{2n^2} + O\left( \frac{1}{n^3}\right) \right)-1 \right] =  \exp \left[ \frac{p-\frac{1}{2}}{n} + O\left( \frac{1}{n^2} \right)  \right]$$ i.e. $$\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}= 1+\frac{p-\frac{1}{2}}{n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$

Now you can conclude using Gauss test.

Comment: I know this representation, but i want to prove with Gaus Test. here $\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}=\frac{1}{e}{(1+\frac{1}{n})}^{n+p}$. I cant represent this with above form.

Comment: @Genieinthebottle Look at my edit.